# YouTube oAuth verification process

Tags: google-oauth, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

For one of our customers we have made a connection in our software with YouTube, by the documented API, for streaming live video-content on the YouTube platform. Therefore we implemented the API-connection in our software, got a test-account and tested our software with de API-connection. Everything is working fine, so we request a verification of the Trust and Safety Team via the OAuth Verification process, so we can use our software for more than just 100 users.

We started the request at the end of May 2020. Although the verification status is showing that we will receive an email within 4 to 6 weeks we still have not received any email or acknowledgement via the developer console. There is no reaction of the team at all.

Is there anyone else who experienced this, if so is there a way to either restart the verification process or get in touch with the Trust and Safety Team at Google/YouTube.

Comment: Is your *OAuth Verification process* in fact the *Google app verification process* as documented by the support doc [Unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en)? If yes, then I recommend to address your issue directly to the company, via its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your response. We already tried addressing our issue on the google issue tracker, but the response we got was that the issue is 'Infeasible' ("Status: Won't Fix (Infeasible)") and with the message that the issue tracker is only for Youtube API issues.